# Validity Sensor (138a:0017) fingerprint reader not working

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I recently bought a Thinkpad (T440p) and installed Ubuntu 13.10.
It should be [certified for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201307-13930/).

But there is one thing, which doesn't work out of the box.
My Validity Sensors fingerprint reader (138a:0017) isn't usable.
How can I configure it and use this in Ubuntu?

Comment: It is certified when preinstalled by the manufacturer, and for Ubuntu 12.04 x64 - though the sensor does seem to show [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201307-13930/components/). I believe you may be able to try using `libfprint`,  but there is a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/827669) that may be relevant.

Comment: libfprint only tells me that it couldn't find my device

Comment: yes I did ... also the bug-report talks about 138a:0018 not 138a:0017 ... ok I'll try compiling it from there

Comment: Dunno then. Sorry. Whoops - you need [this comment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tOQEB.png) that links [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.fprint/2241).

Comment: there is nothing for my device :(

Comment: looks related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/fingerprint-gui/+bug/1341329

Answer (score 1):

Finally the official package libfprint0 in repo of 15.10 does support this reader(138a:0017).

I have a T440p with same fingerprint reader, I've tried it some weeks ago as login credential.

Now I give it up, because comparing with windows driver and application, its accuracy is a bit poor; but at least, it can be correctly recognized by system.